# Node unable to find local module

Tags: node.js, module

I was testing a very simple module to see if it works and keep on getting an error stating that node cannot find my module.

```
//mymodule.js
greeting = 'hello'
module.exports = greeting;

// main.js
const s = require('exportsPractice\mymodule.js');
console.log(s);
```

[The error I get is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7CG2.png)

Comment: are u sure about ur path ?

Comment: Yes I am sure that the path is correct.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot for he files structure

Comment: What is your CWD?, why the "prefix"/path in your require statement "exportsPractice"?! Post the folder structure of your project. BTW: Backslashes have in javascript a special meaning, use normal slashes for your paths, regardless on what platform are you. (or even better use the `normalize` method of the path module.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
const s = require('./exportsPractice/mymodule.js');
```

And make sure the path is correct.

Comment: Same issue, and I know for certain that the path is correct because it was copied form VSC itself.

Comment: Can you share your folder structure?